# Unable to render media from nid:******. Error: No file Id

Tags: nodes, wysiwyg, debugging, media

I'm using node_embed module to embed nodes into the body of my main content type. This works fine but whenever I save a node with embedded nodes within its body I get the notice `Unable to render media from nid:******. Error: No file Id.` Apparently, this is a generic notice generated by /media/modules/media_wysiwyg/includes/media_wysiwyg.filter.inc but it doesn't represent the reality as I'm not really embedding any media.

I've upgraded to the latest version of node_embed and WYSIWYG and this still happens. From the external documentation of node_embed:

> Using Node Embed and Media tags:
>
> The WYSIWG integration of Media breaks the Insert Node input filter
>   and removes its content, because the Media tags are using a simular
>   filter tag format as Node embed. To avoid problems you need to process
>   the Insert Node input filter before the Convert Media tags to Markup
>   input filter.

While this is not exactly the issue I'm experiencing, I understand that this issue has to do with the similarity of the WYSIWYG embed formats between node_embed ([[*]]) and Media module ([[{*}]]).

Note: I'm not even using the `Convert Media tags to markup` filter under /admin/config/content/formats/my_format.

Any ideas on how I can keep my dblog clear from these notices every time I save a node?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a negative lookahead in the regex that traces the media embed tags in media_wysiwyg sub module (media_wysiwyg/includes/media_wysiwyg.filter.inc) seems to do the job.

From the patch submitted on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2894830) for this issue:

```
diff --git a/modules/media_wysiwyg/includes/media_wysiwyg.filter.inc b/modules/media_wysiwyg/includes/media_wysiwyg.filter.inc
index a284752..c9c6130 100644
--- a/modules/media_wysiwyg/includes/media_wysiwyg.filter.inc
+++ b/modules/media_wysiwyg/includes/media_wysiwyg.filter.inc
@@ -455,7 +455,7 @@ function _media_wysiwyg_generate_tagMap($text) {
// between function calls. Since media_process_form is multiple times
// with same form, this function is also called multiple times.
static $tagmap = array();
-  preg_match_all("/\[\[.*?\]\]/s", $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
+  preg_match_all("/\[\[(?!nid:).*?\]\]/s", $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
// We see if tagContent is already in $tagMap, if not we add it
// to $tagmap.  If we return an empty array, we break embeddings of the same
```